# Nvidia Ion HDMI output problems with Acer Revo

Tags: troubleshooting, hdmi, hdtv, nvidia-ion, acer-revo

I bought an Acer Revo.  First I connected it to my Sony TV via HDMI output.  For a few days it worked very well.  Then one day when switching on the computer, it boots and the TV screen turns black and the TV displays the error message *"no input signal"*.

I connected the Revo to a Samsung LED TV, and it did the same.  What do you guys think the problem is? How do I tackle this issue?  Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: first thing to do is connect it with non-HDMI to a real computer monitor; doesn't the Revo have VGA as well as HDMI?  have you tried connecting to a DVI monitor with an HDMI-DVI adapter?

Answer (score 0):

sorry about what I typed above, it was out of frustration. Well here's what happened to me
I initially connected my Revo via HDMI to a samsung HDTV (full HD) during setup. Later on as I wanted to use it with another HDTV (this time NON full HD), the screen shows "Mode Not Supported". Apparently the genius Revo doesn't seem to detect and auto adjust itself when connected to a different TV. So I had to go back to my Full HD tv and reduce the Revo resolution on there to something supported by my non full HD TV, and well that seemed to fix the issue.

If this doesnt help, try changing to a different HDMI port on the TV. If that doesnt help, just chuck it in the bin and go to bed.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung explains it very well here:
http://support-us.samsung.com/cyber/popup/iframe/pop_troubleshooting_fr.jsp?idx=153003

Most of the times it's a refresh-related issue.